# Cholesky with floats 128 (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, long-double

I am trying to use floats 128 to improve the accuracy of very "rough" simulations. However I have a bottleneck with the NumPy's Cholesky decomposition that accepts no more than floats 64.

**Question:** 1) Is there a way to do Cholesky with `np.float128`? (I can do with using another library.)

See below some code to reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np

def get_fractional_std_matrix(t: np.ndarray, H: float):
    s = t[np.newaxis, 1:]
    u = t[1:, np.newaxis]
    H2 = 2 * H
    cov_matrix = ((s ** H2) + (u ** H2) - (np.abs(s - u) ** H2)) / 2

    N = len(t)
    std_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(N, N), dtype=t.dtype)
    std_matrix[1:, 1:] = np.linalg.cholesky(cov_matrix.astype(t.dtype))
    return std_matrix

H = 0.1
t = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=100).astype(np.longdouble)
get_fractional_std_matrix(t=t, H=H)  # TypeError: array type float128 is unsupported in linalg
```

Funnily enough, the addition of `.astype(dtype)` inside cholesky gives me almost the same error on a 64 bit only machine:

```
# TypeError: array type float64 is unsupported in linalg
```

Comment: `float` and `float64` are different types (but same type for CPU/FPU code). To optimize (speed and accuracy) math libraries should check types, not doing the usual python "Duck typing". Are you sure float128 will help? Usually for such type you must use C/C++ and tell compiler that you want operation in the order you specified (order of operations is the main cause of loss of accuracy)

Comment: I am honestly not sure if this causes my problem (for H >> 0.5), but so far it is my best guess, so I wanted to test it ;) Additionally, for the other operations I do with this, floats 128 **substantially** improve accuracy.

Comment: `np.float128` is not actually 128-bit float on most machines. Indeed, it match with the `long double` type in C. AFAIK, on Windows with MSVC, it is 64-bit float so not better than `np.float64`. On mainstream x86-64 PCs, on Linux (or GCC/Clang on Windows), it is typically 80-bit floats (so just a bit better). There is no 128-bit FP hardware unit on x86-64 processor so this should be done in software and this is much more expensive.

Comment: In practice, 64-bit floats are very precise. The error is smaller than the size of the atom radius in a simulation of 1 km wide. Or put it differently : <1 µm for the distance between the earth and the moon. If you need more, then this generally means there is a *numerical instability* in your code and this is what you should fix (instabilities tends to often grow exponentially so increasing the precision by a constant often does not help much and is more expensive, as well as tedious to support).

Comment: LAPACK is the standard basic library used to compute the Cholesky decomposition. Numpy uses it, like most numerical library. It only support 32-bit and 64-bit numbers. If you want a higher precision, then you need to reimplement the primitive yourself (nearly all numerical libraries actually don't support a precision higher than 64-bit). This is not difficult to do (but tedious) if you do not care about performance.

Comment: `mpmath has a `mpmath.cholesky(A, tol=None)¶`

Answer (score 2):

So I did it "by hand" and it seems to work fine with non-complex types including `np.float128`.

```
def cholesky(matrix):
    decomposition = np.zeros_like(matrix)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        temp_sum = matrix[i:, i] - np.einsum("jk, k -> j", decomposition[i:, :i], decomposition[i, :i])
        decomposition[i, i] = np.sqrt(temp_sum[0])
        decomposition[i+1:, i] = temp_sum[1:] / decomposition[i, i]
    return decomposition
```

Comment: Slow but effective